# Rails JavaScript only loads when you Refresh Page, not on the original page load, what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, refresh, turbolinks

## The code works when you refresh the page but not on original load.

Pinterest Clone I'm building. 
Rails App 4.1.4.

.

### What is supposed to happen

When you **click a Pin** from the index page, it takes to SHOW page.
SHOW page has some **JavaScript** which **resizes picture / DIV**.

.

### Problem:

Almost every time I click a Pin from the index page, the javascript does not run (does not resize the image / div).

**BUT** if I click REFRESH with the web browser the script seems to always run just fine (the images / Div get's resized just fine).

.

**Link to js on github:**
https://github.com/growthcode/pinterest/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/pins.js.coffee

**Here it is on Heroku to try it out:**
https://growthcode-pinterest.herokuapp.com/

.

**html of the SHOW pin:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="showPinContainer" class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="showPin" class="well">
        <%= image_tag @pin.image, class: "show-image" %>
        <p class="description"><%= @pin.description %></p>
        <p><%= @pin.user.name %></p>
        <% if current_user == @pin.user %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> |
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

I wrote this in coffee script on rails, I'll list both coffee script and the 'Js2coffee' conversion of it.

**Coffee Script:**

```
# Pin Show page
$ ->
  # set jQuery object variables
  $windowObj = $(window)
  $showPinContainer = $("#showPinContainer")
  $showPin = $("#showPin")
  $showPinImg = $("#showPin img")
  $showPinHeight = $("#showPin").outerHeight()
  $showPinImgWidth = $showPinImg.outerWidth()

  setShowPinContainerHeight = ->
    if $showPinHeight > 450
      $showPinContainer.outerHeight( $showPinHeight )
    else
      $showPinContainer.outerHeight( 450 )

  setShowPinContainerWidth = ->
    if $showPinImgWidth < 200
      $showPinImg.outerWidth( 200 )
    else if $showPinImgWidth > 300 
      $showPinImg.outerWidth( 300 )

  setShowPinContainerSize = ->
    setShowPinContainerHeight()
    setShowPinContainerWidth()

  setShowPinContainerSize()
```

.

**The Js2coffee.com conversion of the above coffee script:**

```
$(function() {
  var $showPin, $showPinContainer, $showPinHeight, $showPinImg, $showPinImgWidth, $windowObj, setShowPinContainerHeight, setShowPinContainerSize, setShowPinContainerWidth;

  $windowObj = $(window);
  $showPinContainer = $("#showPinContainer");
  $showPin = $("#showPin");
  $showPinImg = $("#showPin img");
  $showPinHeight = $("#showPin").outerHeight();
  $showPinImgWidth = $showPinImg.outerWidth();

  setShowPinContainerHeight = function() {
    if ($showPinHeight > 450) {
      return $showPinContainer.outerHeight($showPinHeight);
    } else {
      return $showPinContainer.outerHeight(450);
    }
  };

  setShowPinContainerWidth = function() {
    if ($showPinImgWidth < 200) {
      return $showPinImg.outerWidth(200);
    } else if ($showPinImgWidth > 300) {
      return $showPinImg.outerWidth(300);
    }
  };

  setShowPinContainerSize = function() {
    setShowPinContainerHeight();
    return setShowPinContainerWidth();
  };

  return setShowPinContainerSize();
});
```

---

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so if there is anything else I can provide that would help, please let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: Yep, it was the Turbolinks. I was unaware of how they when starting my first Rails 4+ app. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try disabling Turbolinks.  See the [Rails Guides documentation on Turbolinks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works) for more information.